# Replacing values within a column using if not condition

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have  following data farme,

```
head(df)
    Sample type
    AA01   ph
    AA02   RH
    AA03   CH
    AA04   TCH
```

and I need to replace the values in `column type` if the value is not equal to `ph` to `others`.
And so I tried as following,

```
df$type[which(df$type != "ph")] = "others"
```

But its throwing warning as,

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, which(df$type != "ph"), value = c(NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Any solutions or suggestions would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sample = c("AA01", "AA02", "AA03", "AA04")
type = c("ph", "RH", "CH", "TCH")

df = as.data.frame(cbind(Sample, type))
df$type = as.character(df$type)
df$type = ifelse(df$type == "ph", "others", df$type)
df
```

Comment: I think it might be better to use the recode function from cars.         
 df$Type <- recode(df$Type, "'PH' = 'PH'; else = 'Others'")

Comment: I just did the same thing in two lines, asin firstly, df$type <- ifelse(df$type != "ph", " others", df$type) and then df$type[which(df$type == "5")] = "ph"